# floating effect for text

Tags: html, css, marquee

I want to apply floating effect to some texts. I tried it using marquee.

```css
.bounce {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.bounce p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -moz-transform: translateX(50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
  -moz-animation: bouncing-text 25s linear infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: bouncing-text 25s linear infinite alternate;
  animation: bouncing-text 25s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes bouncing-text {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="bounce">
  <p>SOFT LANDSCAPING</p>
  <br />
  <p>HARD LANDSCAPING</p>
  <br />
</div>
```

This is for bouncing. I want to make the text float like in the water.
Please help me to find a solution. If any other way please let me know.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed problem description. For example, when I put that in a fiddle, I don't see anything at all (even when I add the missing brace). Is that the problem you mean?

Comment: Actually i need up-down movement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with [hover.css](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/). You have to use the code from the `:hover` selector and add it to the element's style itself to make it work.

```
.hvr-bob {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-bob-float, hvr-bob;
  animation-name: hvr-bob-float, hvr-bob;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .3s, 1.5s;
  animation-duration: .3s, 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, .3s;
  animation-delay: 0s, .3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal, alternate;
  animation-direction: normal, alternate;
}
```

Check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamster/bpy80k7x/). Don't forget to add hover.css / hover-min.css.

Comment: happy to help, Saranya.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using css3 animation-name property.

HTML:

```
<div class="floating">
  Floating effect like water
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.floating {
    -webkit-animation-name: Floatingx;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-name: Floating;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Floatingx {
    from {-webkit-transform:translate(0, 0px);}
    65% {-webkit-transform:translate(0, 15px);}
    to {-webkit-transform: translate(0, -0px);}    
}

@-moz-keyframes Floating {
    from {-moz-transform:translate(0, 0px);}
    65% {-moz-transform:translate(0, 15px);}
    to {-moz-transform: translate(0, -0px);}    
}
```

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fa2pwwnc/1/).

For more on how animation-name works, check this out : [animate-name property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-name.asp).